# How can i give input number box default value?

Tags: html, validation, input, format

I've added my number box pattern.

```
<input value="1,2323.23" type="number" pattern="^\\$?(([1-9](\\d*|\\d{0,2}(,\\d{3})*))|0)(\\.\\d{1,2})?$">
```

But I cannot see the value.

Do we have a chance to see this form of value?

Comment: You want type="number"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`type="number"` input can't process values which include the comma so remove that and it should work fine.

```
<input value="12323.23" type="number" pattern="^\\$?(([1-9](\\d*|\\d{0,2}(,\\d{3})*))|0)(\\.\\d{1,2})?$">
```

If you do however, want to keep the comma, then change `type="number"` to `type="text"` and the comma should work fine.

```
<input value="1,2323.23" type="text" pattern="^\\$?(([1-9](\\d*|\\d{0,2}(,\\d{3})*))|0)(\\.\\d{1,2})?$">
```

Here's a JSFiddle with both the above versions: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/65sf2f66/52/

Answer (score 1):

If you want comma then try to use `type="text"` instead.

```
<input value="1,2323.23" type="text" pattern="^\\$?(([1-9](\\d*|\\d{0,2}(,\\d{3})*))|0)(\\.\\d{1,2})?$">
```

**[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/f39kx1tr/)**

Answer (score 0):

You were just missing the `placeholder="123"` attribute :)

```
<input placeholder="123" value="1,2323.23" type="number" pattern="^\\$?(([1-9](\\d*|\\d{0,2}(,\\d{3})*))|0)(\\.\\d{1,2})?$">
```

DEMO:
https://jsfiddle.net/f39kx1tr/